# ラズパイ×I2CでNFCの読み込みを検証したい

Tags: raspberry-pi

ラズパイ3 model Bで、I2CでのIDmの読み出しを検証しようとしています。

```
root@xxx:/home/xxx# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- 24 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

USBタイプのNFCではなく、GPIOでラズパイに認識させることはできたのですが、
CLIからSuicaやAndroidのIDmを読み込むことはできるのでしょうか？

nfcpyなどは試したのですが、USBで接続したNFCモジュールしか扱えない？ようでした。

また、i2cgetで取得したデータはなんのデータなのでしょうか？

```
root@xxx:/home/xxx# i2cget 1 0x24
WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus, cause data loss and worse!
I will read from device file /dev/i2c-1, chip address 0x24, current data
address, using read byte.
Continue? [Y/n] y
0x80
```

Comment: 用いているNFCモジュールの型番などは分かりますでしょうか？
データシートがわかれば回答のヒントになるかもしれません。